# Python dictionary of dictionaries, counting element value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a following python dictionary

```
resultDict: 
{'1234':{'alertStatus': 'open', 'reasonDescription': None}, 
'4321': {'alertStatus': 'closed', 'reasonDescription': 'Public'},
'6789': {'alertStatus': 'open', 'reasonDescription': 'None'}}
```

I want to count number of open and closed alerts (in real i have 5 different status, but for this example i have reduced it to 2)

I have written the following code , but it looks pretty untidy. I was wondering if there is a better way to do it

```
result = {}
result['length'] = len(resultDict)
lenOpen = 0
lenClosed = 0

for notifications in resultDict.values():
    if notifications['alertStatus'] == 'open':
        lenOpen = lenOpen + 1
    if notifications['alertStatus'] == 'closed':
        lenClosed  = lenClosed + 1

statusCount = []
if lenOpen > 0:
    statusCount.append(str(lenOpen) + ' ' + 'open')
if lenOpenUnderInvestigation > 0:
    statusCount.append(str(lenClosed) + ' ' +'closed')

result['statusCount'] = statusCount
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
In [2]: dic={'1234':{'alertStatus': 'open', 'reasonDescription': None}, 
   ...: '4321': {'alertStatus': 'closed', 'reasonDescription': 'Public'},
   ...: '6789': {'alertStatus': 'open', 'reasonDescription': 'None'}}

In [3]: from collections import Counter

In [4]: Counter(v['alertStatus'] for k,v in dic.items())

Out[4]: Counter({'open': 2, 'closed': 1})
```

**help(Counter)**:

> Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag or
>   multiset.  Elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are
>   stored as dictionary values.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
alertStatuses = [x['alertStatus'] for x in resultDict.values()]
```

Then you can count the elements from there with the [Counter object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).